# Integrating the equation for change in entropy

Tags: calculus, integration, physics

In physics, the change in entropy is defined as
$$dS = \frac{dQ}{T}$$

I tried integrating this.
$$\int ds=\frac{1}{T}\int dQ$$
$$S=\frac{Q}{T}+C$$
This essentially converts the change in entropy to absolute entropy. I’m dubious as to whether this is right. At lower temperatures, absolute entropy should be decreasing, not increasing. Yet I did the integration, and this is the result I got. Can anyone explain what I did wrong? And if I didn’t do anything wrong, can anyone explain why this result is so strange?

Comment: What you did is (mathematically) perfectly correct, provided that the temperature $T$ is a constant.

Comment: @Nicolas Then why is the solution so strange?

Comment: @ligtweaver Even before integrating, $\mathrm{d}S=\mathrm{d}Q/T$ tells you that, for strictly non-negative temperatures $T$, the infinitesimal variation of the heat $Q$ must be non-positive, as you want the infinitesimal variation of the entropy $S$ to be non-positive. So you can interpret it as it : for isolated systems with constant temperature, the infinitesimal variation of heat (if there is any) is non-positive. But have these systems any physical sense ?

Comment: @Nicolas What do you mean by “physical sense”?

Comment: I meant that isolated systems with variation of heat do not exist in nature. The point is that we often simplify some hypothesis to make the problem easier (here we assumed a constant temperature), but the resulting model does not describe very well the physical reality.

Comment: You can't do this because Q is a function of temperature, recall the first law.